# Language for running processes on server for multiple users

Tags: php, web-applications, process, streaming

Hi I'd like to create a web application that collects data from Twitter. The problem is that the user has to insert the time he wants the server to collect data from Twitter. How do I do that? I've thought of using the Search API of Twitter but then how do I control the running time for the process? If the user leaves the page will it still run? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use cron jobs.

Comment: Are you using linux/unix  or windows

Comment: Thanks for the answer user1718294. While developing I will be using Windows but I think the Server will run Linux. The cron job seems a good solution. Can you think anything similar like cron jobs for Windows?